# Android Exception android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: android, xamarin, broadcastreceiver, localnotification

I have a lot of crashes on Play Store that I don't know where are coming from or how to reproduce. The stack trace is pointing to **ScheduledAlarmHandler**. This leads me to believe that the crashes happen when the app is in the background (or killed) and a local notification is fired.

`Exception android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s  at System.IO.StringReader..ctor (System.String s) [0x00009] in <2f4adfad501c4e4abfe6a9b300c1b849>:0    at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StringReader..ctor(string)   at LocalNotifications.Plugin.ScheduledAlarmHandler.serializeFromString (System.String notificationString) [0x00010] in <42e60f59bb2b4f93942a1c96f54643af>:0    at LocalNotifications.Plugin.ScheduledAlarmHandler.OnReceive (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Content.Intent intent) [0x0000c] in <42e60f59bb2b4f93942a1c96f54643af>:0    at Android.Content.BroadcastReceiver.n_OnReceive_Landroid_content_Context_Landroid_content_Intent_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_context, System.IntPtr native_intent) [0x00017] in <1eada6631e384353908e0dab9d072f35>:0    at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLL_V (_JniMarshal_PPLL_V callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz, System.IntPtr p0, System.IntPtr p1) [0x00005] in <1eada6631e384353908e0dab9d072f35>:0    at crc6449389a0f4059adff.ScheduledAlarmHandler.n_onReceive   at crc6449389a0f4059adff.ScheduledAlarmHandler.onReceive (ScheduledAlarmHandler.java:30)   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4497)   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600 (ActivityThread.java:301)   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2188)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)   at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8653)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)`

I tried wrapping the code in .OnReceive within a **PowerManager.WakeLock** but it doesn't help.

The exact code to which the stack points is

'''[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]

public class ScheduledAlarmHandler : BroadcastReceiver
{
   
    public const string LocalNotificationKeyText = "LocalNotification_TEXT";
    public const string LocalNotificationKeyID = "LocalNotification_ID";
    public const string LocalNotificationKeyTitle = "LocalNotification_TITLE";
    public NotificationManager manager;
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "ScheduledAlarmHandler");
            wakeLock.Acquire();
            var id = intent.GetIntExtra(LocalNotificationKeyID, 0);
            var title = intent.GetStringExtra(LocalNotificationKeyTitle);
            var text = intent.GetStringExtra(LocalNotificationKeyText);

            var notification = new LocalNotification();
            notification.Title = title;
            notification.Text = text;
            notification.Id = id;

            manager = getNotificationManager();
            var nativeNotification = createNativeNotification(context, notification);

            if (notification.Id == 909092)
            {
                //Remove ongoing notification that you have an active session
                manager.Cancel(909093);
            }
            manager.Notify(notification.Id, nativeNotification);
            wakeLock.Release();
        }
    }

    private NotificationManager getNotificationManager()
    {
        var notificationManager = Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
        return notificationManager;
    }'''
```

Any guidance or help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean the error didn't appear when you debug and release the project? And the broadcastreceiver's onreceive method will trigger when the device on boot( not the background and be killed).

Comment: yes, my suspicion is that something goes wrong between intent.GetStringExtra and creating a local notification with the data

Comment: It seems the crash came from the LocalNotifications.Plugin, did you check the package's supported android version?